# Uploading unique files at concurrent load using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

We have usecase where we need to call an API that uploads its respective category of unique file.
For every API call we need to use a unique FileName. I mean File once used in an API call should not be used again.
For Example
CarAPI will be called by uploading a file-name from list of files (CarAP_1.xml to CarAP_1000.xml files)
File CarAP_1.xml once used in an API call should not be used again in next call

BikeAPI will be called by uploading a file-name from list of files (BikeAP_1.xml to BikeAP_1000.xml files)
File once used in an API call should not be used again.

Any thoughts or inputs on how we can achieve this using JMeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put these filenames

- either to a CSV file and use [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/), its [READ](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#READ) endpoint has `KEEP=false` mode so once the data is used it will be removed from memory hence you can avoid duplicate requests
- or to [Redis](https://redis.io/) and use [Redis Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-redis-data-set-an-introduction) which also provides possibility to remove the data from the list once it has been utilized

Both plugins can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)